# Deck GL set MVT point layer icon faces camera

Tags: javascript, deck, gl

I'm attempting  to set the MVT layer icon to faces camera in Deck GL (version 8.8). Currently, I use first person view and MVT layers. The problem is that currently the points faces up. I would like to change it to face to the camera.
I tried with 'billboard: true' option, but it makes no sense.

How can I do it?

This is my code:

```
  new deck.MVTLayer({
      id: 'points',
      data: `http://127.0.0.1:7800/data.points/{z}/{x}/{y}.pbf`,
      loadOptions: {
          mvt: {
              layers: ['data.points']
          }
      },
      minZoom: 0,
      maxZoom: 23,
      radiusMinPixels: 6,
      radiusMaxPixels: 10,
      getPointRadius: 6,
      getLineColor: [255, 255, 255],
      getFillColor: [255,0,0],
      getLineWidth: 1,
      lineWidthMinPixels: 1,
      billboard: true
      })
```